# How can I add pg_monitor role to a postgresql user on heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, datadog

I'm trying to set up a Datadog PostgreSQL integration that requires a user with `pg_monitor` role and `SELECT` permission on `pg_stat_database` as described on their own [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgres/?tab=host#configuration).

My database is currently hosted on Heroku and it seems the default user doesn't have `SUPERUSER`permissions because, when I try to apply the above role and permission to a "monitor" user I have the following error message:

> ERROR:  must have admin option on role "pg_monitor"

So I'm looking for some way of:

- grant the necessary permissions to that user without being a superuser
- get superuser access on Heroku Postgres (what I think is [not possible](https://help.heroku.com/IV1DHMS2/can-i-get-superuser-privileges-or-create-a-superuser-in-heroku-postgres))

Someone has ever faced this issue? There is a way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to open a ticket asking the Heroku CS team to apply the "pg_monitor" role to my user. They've granted the role and now everything is working fine